# Google books api limit per user

Tags: android, api, limit, google-books

We want to build a mobile application that, as part of 
it's functionality, could search for books using the Google Books API; 
however since all users will be using the same application's API key to 
make requests, we believe the 1000 quota will be over pretty quickly. Is 
there a way to make something like this viable? If every user signs in with 
its Google account could we generate an OAuth token for each user and the 
limit will count per user token and not for the entire application?